# How can I make the left div expand and the right div have constant width?

Tags: html, css

So as the title says, I want to put two divs right next to each other, and have the left one expand if the window is expanded, while the right one stays at a constant width.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
<body>
    <div id="content" style="background-color: red">
        <div id="left" style="margin-right: 100px; background-color: blue">
            This</br>is</br>left.
        </div>
        <div id="right" style="float: right; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green">
            This</br>is</br>right.
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</bod>
```

Which produces this:

[image: It is quite sad if you can't see this :(]

Ideally, the green square and blue square should have their tops aligned with each other. One solution I found was putting a negative margin-top setting on the green div, which works... but only as long as the blue div never changes in height. Unfortunately, the blue div can in fact change height in my situation.

Any ideas on how I'd fix this? I'm having some difficulty understanding the intricacies of CSS positioning :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `position:absolute`, you can do something like this:

```
<div class="left">This is the left box.</div>
<div class="right">This is the right box.</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 100px;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TKU/

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered nesting them ?

http://jsfiddle.net/bonatoc/N3xWn/

```
<div id="content" style="background-color: red">
    <div id="left" style=" background-color: blue">

        <div id="right" style="display:inline-block; float: right; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green">
        This</br>is</br>right.
        </div>

    This</br>is</br>left.
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way.

If this is your HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">This</br>is</br>left.</div>
    <div id="right">This</br>is</br>right.</div>
</div>
```

Try the following CSS:

```css
#content {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100px;
}
#left {
    margin-right: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: auto;
}
#right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/GfpyL/

Your logo in the `#right` element has specific dimensions, so position it absolutely to the top right of the parent `#content` element which has `position: relative` to set the point of reference for the absolute positioning.

Add a min-height to the parent block to prevent it from collapsing for those cases where the `#left` block is less than 100px in height.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `flexbox`? flexbox help you control these width flexibility.
If you set left content as a 100px, right box width is flexibility.

HTML below :

```
<div id="content" >
    <div id="left">
         This<br>is<br>left.
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        This<br>is</br>right.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS below:

```
#content {
    /* old*/
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-box;
    display: box;
    /* New */
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flexbox;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

#left {
    /* old */
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
       -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
        -ms-box-ordinal-group: 1;
            box-ordinal-group: 1;
    /* New */
    -webkit-flex-order: 1;
       -moz-flex-order: 1;
        -ms-flex-order: 1;
            flex-order: 1;

   /* Old */
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
       -moz-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-box-flex: 1;
            box-flex: 1;

    /* New */
    width: -webkit-flex(1);
    width: -moz-flex(1);
    width: -ms-flex(1);
    width: flex(1);
 }

 #right {
      width: 100px;

      /* Old */
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
         -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
          -ms-box-ordinal-group: 2;
              box-ordinal-group: 2;

      /* New */
      -webkit-flex-order: 2;
         -moz-flex-order: 2;
          -ms-flex-order: 2;
              flex-order: 2;
```

}

Here is jsfiddle code below : 
http://jsfiddle.net/sota0805/kykU7/

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use make use of block formatting contexts to fill remaining width.

1) Float the first child of a div

2) Set `overflow:auto` (or hidden) on the second child to fill remaining width

So this would work too:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Se5Nm/2/)**

### Markup:

```
<div class="wpr">
    <div class="rFloat"></div>
    <div class="blue overflow" contenteditable>this is left</div>

    <div class="rFloat green">This is right</div>
    <div class="overflow"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wpr {
    background: red;
    min-width: 200px;
}
div {
    min-height: 20px;
}
.rFloat {
    width: 100px;
    float:right;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;  
}
.green {
    background: green;
}
.overflow {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Notice that in the fiddle I have set the `contenteditable` attribute to true on the blue div - so you can type in the blue area and see that it expands as required.